# I am unable to show the custom data value in apex chart tooltip

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I want to show the 3rd key time value in the corresponding tooltip in Apex charts.

[showing the empty value instead of showing 3 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ibz2.png)

Here is the apex chart data series and options and tooltip content. Here it is showing empty value

```
export const DeveloperSizing = () => {
    const data = {
        series: [{
            name: 'Size:Xs',
            data: [44, 55, 41, 80, 10, 44, 22],
            time: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12]
        }],

        options: {
            xaxis: {
                title: {
                    text: "Tickets"
                },
                categories: ["12/01/23 - 12/03/23", "12/01/23 - 12/03/23", "12/01/23 - 12/03/23", "12/01/23 - 12/03/23", "12/01/23 - 12/03/23", "12/01/23 - 12/03/23", "All"],
                labels: {
                    formatter: function (val) {
                        return val
                    }
                }
            },
            yaxis: {
                title: {
                    text: "Sprints",
                    offset: '0px'
                },
            },
            tooltip: {
                y: {
                    formatter: function (val) {
                        return "Time: " + data.series[val.seriesIndex].time[val.dataPointIndex] + " days";
                    }
                }
            },
            fill: {
                opacity: 1
            },
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
                horizontalAlign: 'center',
                offsetX: 40
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ReactApexChart
                options={data.options}
                series={data.series}
                type='bar'
                height={400}
                className='apex-charts'
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out
https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/

[image: Tooltip Y Formatter]

Try like that using the second parameter

```
tooltip: {
  y: {
    formatter: function (val, e) {
      return "Time: " + e.w.config.series[e.seriesIndex].time[e.dataPointIndex] + " days";
    }
  }
}
```